# How to use CSS :not() properly?

Tags: html, css

I just looked up the [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/%3anot) pseudo-class and tried the example there. Interestingly it looks different on my local computer than on the MDN site.

Compare [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Jqxr/) and [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/%3anot#Examples).

```css
p:not(.classy) { color: red; }
:not(p) { color: green; }
```

```html
<p>Some text.</p>
<p class="classy">Some other text.</p>
<span>One more text</span>
```

The output:

> Some text. <-- This is red.
>
> Some other text. <-- This is green?! (It should be black or whatever is the default color)
>
> One more text <-- This is green.

Upon inspecting the element, I found that `Some other text` somehow inherits the color green from the `body`, which is affected by `:not(p)`.

So why is the MDN site showing it correctly? It's a *trick*:

```html
<p style="color: red;">Some text.</p>
<p>Some other text.</p>
<p style="color: green;">One more text</p>
```

So my question is, how to use `:not()` **properly** and prevent inheritance from causing unexpected outcomes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, both are correct. ;)
In jsFiddle, try to define a default color first, like

```
body { color: blue; }
```

Right now, body has no special color set, so `:not(p)` applies to body, too, and p.classy inherits the color from body.

See http://jsfiddle.net/3Jqxr/1/ for updated example.

EDIT: Since the specifity of the `:not` selector is higher than a simple `body` in CSS, you actually have to set the default color with

```
body:not(p)
```

for this example.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't set a a default value for `<p>`, your `<p class="classy">` element inherits from body. You probably want to exclude `<body>` from the ruleset:

```
body :not(p) { color: green; }
```

Alternatively, you can set a default:

```
p{ color: black; }
p:not(.classy) { color: red; }
:not(p) { color: green; }
```